# Python pickle 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pickle

I'm currently trying to load a pickled file but I'm getting this error: 
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Model'`

I have the following folder structur

```
 project/
  - run.py
  - module/
    - module.py
       - #class Model()
    - __init__.py
```

The class I want to import is a `module.Model` and
I use this to load the File:

```
import cPickle as pickle
import module
with open("myModelPath") as mf:
    m = pickle.load(mf)
```

If I run this in the `project/module` subfolder everything works fine but if I try to run the following in my `project/`folder I get an error

```
import cPickle as pickle
import module.module
with open("myModelPath") as mf:
    m = pickle.load(mf)
```

I think the problem is, that my Model is now a `module.module.Model`. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're defining the class in `module.module` instead of just `module`? I mean no package, but just a module.

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly. my `Model` class is defined in the module `module` and everything is working fine if I stay within the subfolder. In the module folder is a third-party-software which I want to use. And since I don't want to mix things with my own work I wanted to put those files into a subfolder (here the module folder).

I have to admit, for someone who ususally uses Scala/Java the whole module system in python is quite confusing.

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from the fact the in Python packages can contain code. You can define classes and functions in the `__init__.py` file and you can access them directly from the package, no module involved. Also most of times, just having modules is good enough and packages are not that much required. That's what I asked on the comment. Do you have a strong reason to define your class in a module under a package, and not just in a module. Which I guess the answer is because you'd want to separate 3rd party software.